# Angle is off in dynamic Torus Mesh Generation

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, math, geometry

I have a code for dynamically generating a Torus Segment depending on an angle (which I basically took from [ProceduralPrimitives](http://wiki.unity3d.com/index.php/ProceduralPrimitives) and made some changes to use the input angle instead of creating a complete torus):

```
public class DynamicTorusSegment : MonoBehaviour
{
    [Range(0, 360)] public float CurrentAngle;

    [SerializeField] private int _maxSegments = 20;
    [SerializeField] private float _radius1 = 1f;
    [SerializeField] private float _radius2 = 0.3f;
    [SerializeField] private int _nbSides = 5;

    // For checking if the Angle was changed since the last frame
    private float _lastAngle;
    private const float TwoPi = Mathf.PI * 2f;

    // Update is called once per frame
    private void Update()
    {
        if (Mathf.Approximately(CurrentAngle, _lastAngle)) return;

        _lastAngle = CurrentAngle;
        GenerateTorus(CurrentAngle);
    }

    private void GenerateTorus(float angle)
    {
        var meshFilter = GetComponent<MeshFilter>();
        var mesh = meshFilter.mesh;
        mesh.Clear();

        var segmentsCount = (int)(_maxSegments * angle / 360);
        if (!Mathf.Approximately(angle, 0))
        {
            segmentsCount = Mathf.Clamp(segmentsCount, 2, _maxSegments);
        }


        #region Vertices        
        var vertices = new Vector3[(segmentsCount + 1) * (_nbSides + 1)];

        for (var segment = 0; segment < segmentsCount; segment++)
        {
            var currentSegment = segment == segmentsCount ? 0 : segment;

            var t1 = (float)currentSegment / segmentsCount * TwoPi / 360 * angle;
            var r1 = new Vector3(Mathf.Cos(t1) * _radius1, 0f, Mathf.Sin(t1) * _radius1);

            for (var side = 0; side <= _nbSides; side++)
            {
                var currentSide = side == _nbSides ? 0 : side;

                var t2 = (float)currentSide / _nbSides * TwoPi;
                var r2 = Quaternion.AngleAxis(-t1 * Mathf.Rad2Deg, Vector3.up) * new Vector3(Mathf.Sin(t2) * _radius2, Mathf.Cos(t2) * _radius2);

                vertices[side + segment * (_nbSides + 1)] = r1 + r2;
            }
        }
        #endregion

        #region Normales        
        var normals = new Vector3[vertices.Length];
        for (var segment = 0; segment < segmentsCount; segment++)
        {
            var currentSegment = segment == segmentsCount ? 0 : segment;

            var t1 = (float)currentSegment / segmentsCount * TwoPi / 360 * angle;
            var r1 = new Vector3(Mathf.Cos(t1) * _radius1, 0f, Mathf.Sin(t1) * _radius1);

            for (var side = 0; side <= _nbSides; side++)
            {
                normals[side + segment * (_nbSides + 1)] = (vertices[side + segment * (_nbSides + 1)] - r1).normalized;
            }
        }
        #endregion

        #region UVs
        var uvs = new Vector2[vertices.Length];
        for (var segment = 0; segment < segmentsCount; segment++)
        {
            for (var side = 0; side <= _nbSides; side++)
            {
                uvs[side + segment * (_nbSides + 1)] = new Vector2((float)segment / segmentsCount, (float)side / _nbSides);
            }
        }
        #endregion

        #region Triangles
        var faceCount = vertices.Length;
        var triangleCount = faceCount * 2;
        var indexesCount = triangleCount * 3;
        var triangles = new int[indexesCount];

        var i = 0;
        for (var segment = 0; segment < segmentsCount - 1; segment++)
        {
            for (var side = 0; side <= _nbSides - 1; side++)
            {
                var current = side + segment * (_nbSides + 1);
                var next = side + (segment < (segmentsCount) ? (segment + 1) * (_nbSides + 1) : 0);

                if (i >= triangles.Length - 6) continue;

                triangles[i++] = current;
                triangles[i++] = next;
                triangles[i++] = next + 1;

                triangles[i++] = current;
                triangles[i++] = next + 1;
                triangles[i++] = current + 1;
            }
        }
        #endregion

        mesh.vertices = vertices;
        mesh.normals = normals;
        mesh.uv = uvs;
        mesh.triangles = triangles;

        mesh.RecalculateBounds();
    }
}
```

This basically works fine and creates the Torus segment depending on the `CurrentAngle`

[image]

But as you might have noticed already something is wrong with my code/math.

The main problem is: The torus isn't complete on 360°.

[image]

But when I tested it further I noticed that actually already before e.g. 90° isn't correct neither:

[image]

So currently in order to get a closed torus I have to use an angle somewhere between 378° and 379°. So it seems that there is allways that missing offset of 19° .. but where does this come from? (It also appears to work for small angles so I have a segment also for `angle < 19°`)

**Does somebody see what I'm doing wrong here?**

---

**Update**

This number of `19°` actually seems to depend on `(360° / _maxSegments ) = 18,5°` (in my example `_maxSegments` was 20) and actually gets smaller or bigger depending on that `_maxSegments` value.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Extracting two lines from the original code:

```
Vector3[] vertices = new Vector3[(nbRadSeg+1) * (nbSides+1)];

for( int seg = 0; seg <= nbRadSeg; seg++ )
                      ^^
```

... and the corresponding lines from your own code:

```
var vertices = new Vector3[(segmentsCount + 1) * (_nbSides + 1)];

for (var segment = 0; segment < segmentsCount; segment++)
                              ^
```

Note that the second loop condition is `<` instead of `<=` which it should be. This means you are skipping the final segment.

And since the angular span of a segment is ~18.5° in your example, the ~19° systematic disparity you observed is no coincidence.

Note that the same problem occurs for the normal, UV and triangle generation loops as well.

Comment: No that doesn't solve it.  The last one only connected a trinagle with the starting point so the torus got "closed" but via a very ugly triangle between the last segment and the first segment. When I left that in I also got a lot of exceptions like `Assertion failed: Converting invalid MinMaxAABB`, `Assertion failed: Invalid worldAABB. Object is too large or too far away from the origin.` basically apparently due to division by 0 I guess

Comment: @derHugo in that case you would need an extra clause to handle the case when the torus is closed. I'll update with some sample code.

Comment: You can save your time! Your were right .. I only removed the `=` due to the exceptions I got. But the original mistake is already in the line for the triangles:  `for (var segment = 0; segment < segmentsCount - 1; segment++)` .. the `-1` (I'm supid :D ) is actually just a relict from a former test. So it should be `<=` for all lops except the last one there it is only `<` and works now thanks. And I will just skip if the Angle is to small so it can cause no trouble for `0`

Comment: @derHugo I see, no problem haha; I saw the `-1` bit too (another disparity with the original code) and thought about mentioning it, but decided against that in the end